# how to show images in another script after uploading it via a php script to a mysql database?

Tags: php

After creation a addscore.php script i uploaded images to mysql database via a form and move those images via move_uploaded_file() function. i can see those image files in my www file in my server. i created a uploads folder in which those images are moving to. Now i am trying to show those image in a different website using,

```
    echo '<img src="uploads/'.$row['screenshot'].'" alt="score image"/>';
```

But the images are not showing.....
can anyone help me with this?????

Comment: If it is a different website you would need the whole URL.

Comment: And also what if you manually upload a picture there, just check your path, whether you adress it correctly

Comment: Are you using the correct path for ```"uploads/"``` considering the file where are you working?

Comment: Remember that the *file path* and the *file URL* are often two different things. Your URL is based on the path **relative to the web root**.

Comment: @JayBlanchard no it is not a different website. i have index.php and addscore.php in the same folder. uploads file is also in the same folder.

Comment: @Undry yes i also tried that. i set the src attribute to "uploads/imagename.gif" and it worked fine.

Comment: @ProblemChild yes all php files and uploads file is situated under www file of my server.

Comment: I did not read that. If the destination is another web page, you must put the absolute path, not the relative, of the image to be displayed. I assume you are using them on localhost, in that case it will be ```localhost/yourwebsite /...``` or you can try with ```../uploads/``` because you are saying that the folder with the images is inside the ```www``` directory